# how to stop future internet explorer updates on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, internet-explorer, automatic-updates

Is there a way to disable future updates of Internet Explorer on a windows server 2012 R2 system? In the IE11 -> "About Internet Explorer" window there is no check box anymore for "Install new versions automatically". Strange because windows 8.1 still has it. I want the latest and greatest right now, but want to keep this servers application stable and not have any other uncontrolled updates.

Is there a registry settings or group policy for this? I'm not seeing one. 
Thank you

EDIT: I think I found it, won't know for sure until IE12 comes out though:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"EnableAutoUpgrade"=dword:00000000

Answer (score 1):

How are  you receiving Windows Updates?  Via. a controlled WSUS server, or directly from Microsoft's Automatic Update service?  If it's via WSUS you can remove these updates from the WSUS server, or control the method you are approving updates.  If it's from the automatic update service from Microsoft, I think your best bet is hiding the updates in the Windows Update app (start->run->wuapp) then finding the update for Internet Explorer and right click -> Hide Update.  This will prevent it from showing up again, but you will have to do it again for the next version available.

Comment: We are updating via normal automatic updates. These app servers are not on a domain. We want all the security updates but don't want to change IE because of how ingrained it is with windows and our developer doesn't want "something to change" that "might break something in the future". Need a setting that doesn't allow IE to major update without any manual future actions by me. I don't want to have to remember to jump back on the servers to block an update.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40722

Comment: I assume that just stops IE11 which I already have, not auto installs of IE12/13 (as an example).

Comment: WSUS is your best bet, and your servers don't need to be on a domain to use it.  It just makes the setup a little harder without the domain GPO.